# Missing value in enumeration array

Tags: matlab

How do you represent a missing value in an array of enumeration values?

For other data types we can use NaN or missing. Using this example enumeration class:

```
classdef MyEnum
   enumeration
      A
      B
   end
end
```

I've tried:

```
>> [ MyEnum.A MyEnum.B missing ]
Error using horzcat
The following error occurred converting from missing to MyEnum:
Unsupported conversion from 'missing' to enumeration 'MyEnum'.

>> [ MyEnum.A MyEnum.B NaN ]
Error using horzcat
The following error occurred converting from double to MyEnum:
Cannot call the constructor of 'MyEnum' outside of its enumeration block.
```

It seems like I'm missing something very basic here... Please help!

Comment: Define `MyEnum.None`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two ways to do so:

1. define a 'nan' psaudo enum.
2. make the class a successor of a double superclass (like here).

Comment: Good idea for providing two options. I'm going to use the first in my application as I can't inherit from a value class in this case. For posterity, you could add some code examples for the two options in your answer.